# What does the dotting of two string mean in pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode, notation

I'm having trouble understanding the notation of [this pseudocode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f05np.jpg)

The line in particular I don't understand is:

```
LeftPart (PartialWord [dot] l, N', limit - 1)
```

What does the dot represent?

Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you tag this as C++?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm trying to implement the algorithm in C++ and I suppose I subconsciously included it as a tag.

Comment: For future reference, including images of text instead of just pasting the text into the question is not really appreciated here. And for questions of the form "What does *X* mean when s/he uses tbe notation *γ*?", it is usually helpful to know who *X* is and what paper or book *γ* appeared in.

Comment: Will do next time. Thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "create a new word consisting of the letters in *PartialWord* followed by an *l*". (Or more simply, "append *l* to *PartialWord*", but I was trying to be clear that *PartialWord* isn't actually modified.)